# How to generate documentation with typer-cli from a python script

Tags: python, typer

I am working on a CLI tool written in Python with [Typer](https://typer.tiangolo.com/). We have some bash scripts which I am currently rewriting in Python and one of them generates markdown documentation for the tool using [typer-cli](https://typer.tiangolo.com/typer-cli/). I know I can use Python's [Subprocess management](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) to call it, but I would prefer not to.

The idea is to make all scripts completely platform-independent by rewriting them in Python and although the current `subprocess` approach with that particular call is most likely perfectly fine, I am very curious how to do it otherwise.

I looked into typer-cli's source code and found that I should probably make a call to [docs()](https://github.com/tiangolo/typer-cli/blob/master/typer_cli/main.py#L263).

This is the code I would like to replace:

```
# TODO: try to use typer_cli.main.docs here instead
typer_args = (
    f"typer {PATH_KPOPS_MAIN} utils docs --name kpops --output {PATH_CLI_COMMANDS_DOC}"
)
subprocess.run(typer_args, shell=True)
```

I also read about the [Context](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.1.x/api/#click.Context) object, but still, I didn't understand how to get the context from the Typer app `kpops` to pass it to `typer-cli`'s `docs` function.